# Code for executing method every day at specific time C# (Windows Service) failed

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I had this code to execute method of windows service every day at 5am:

EDIT:

```
MyService ws = new MyService ();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (serviceHost != null)
    {
        serviceHost.Close();
    }

    serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

    serviceHost.Open();
    double TimeOfExecution = 5;

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime today5am = now.Date.AddHours(TimeOfExecution);
    DateTime next5am = now <= today5am ? today5am : today5am.AddDays(1);

    System.Threading.TimerCallback callback = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(ws.MethodToExecute());

    var timer1 = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, next5am - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

 }
```

I expected the Service to execute at next 5 o'clock, and every 24 hours after that.

Method `MethodToExecute()` did get executed at 5 o'clock (or some other specified time) that day, but next day it failed to execute. Also, it seems that it does not matter if I executed it or not for the first time, but it seems like service goes to sleep after some time and doesn't execute, so if 5 o'clock arrives not at current day, but next day, it will fail to execute.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you post more code? Specifically, did you make sure your timer survives until the next day? The use of var indicates a local variable...

Comment: Note that this will not handle time changes.  If you have DST, it could change to 6am or 4am.

Comment: Instead of making this a service, if you want it to run at a specific point in time, you could consider making it a normal console application, and running it with the Windows Task Scheduler

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa I have several methods within service that runs at different hours and do different things (one method runs at 8 am, second at 3 pm, and third at 9 pm), so I think it is easier to set this this way than to make three console applications that will run on different times and do different things, especially if you have many methods, I do not know, maybe it is just personal preference...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GC will collect your `timer` since you don't have any references to it after `OnStart` method.

You're just having it as a local variable. I hope you know local variables are eligible for garbage collection once JIT says that they are no longer used in code.

Fix: Just store the `timer` in a instance variabe, you're done.

```
private System.Threading.Timer my5AmTimer = null;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    //All other code..

   this.my5AmTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, next5am - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how is it possible that the method gets executed for the first time, if timer is garbage collected as soon as OnStart method is left?

Comment: @user3048706 *I hope you know local variables are eligible for garbage collection once JIT says that they are no longer used in code.* It's *eligible* for GC. The GC runs when it needs to. It doesn't run all the time. Consider reading the manual for more information.

Comment: @ta.speot.is You should read my statement again. I never stated that GC runs all the time. I said it is **eligible** for garbage collection which is correct. Any comments?

Comment: *@ta.speot.is You should read my statement again. I never stated that GC runs all the time. I said it is eligible for garbage collection which is correct. Any comments? – Sriram Sakthivel 1 min ago* @SriramSakthivel Read my comment. Specifically the part where I say *The GC runs when it needs to* and *It doesn't run all the time.* Take specific note of the part where I quote your comment, and place emphasis on the word *eligible*.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Am sorry, I think I take you wrong, So you're providing more info to OP right?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That's what the `@user3048706` part means.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I know that I missed to see that, nervermind Sorry if I offended you :)

Comment: Thank you for your comments and help! I have to test if this will work tomorrow, and then I will accept the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var timer1 = new System.Threading.Timer(...);
```

Timers are tricky objects.  They are subject to garbage collection, just like any .NET objects, when they are no longer referenced.  The syntax of this statement is enough to know when that happens, your usage of `var` shows that "timer1" is a *local variable* of a method.  In other words, there is no reference left to that Timer object you created after your method returns.

So what exactly keeps a Timer alive and ticking when there is *no* reference left?  You found out: nothing.  Whether your timer will actually tick is a crapshoot.  If your program keeps running doing other things then it triggers a gen#0 collection and the timer will disappear.  It will never tick.  If your program doesn't then it will survive long enough to make it to 5am.

You *must* store the object reference in a variable that ensures it survives long enough.  That should be a *static* variable.

Or use a System.Timers.Timer.  It acts a lot like a System.Threading.Timer but has better survival skills.  It is guaranteed to stay alive as long as it has an Elapsed event handler and it is enabled.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thank you on your help! And will my ws variable from MyService ws = new MyService (); live long enough. Should I make it static too?

Comment: Impossible to guess.  Don't just arbitrarily make variables static.  Sounds like that timer should be a field in MyService so it is kept alive as long as the service is alive.

Answer (score 0):

Please [read the fine manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ## Note
>
> As long as you are using a Timer, you must keep a reference to it. As with any managed object, a Timer is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected.

Keep a reference to it:

```
MyService ws = new MyService ();

System.Threading.Timer timer;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    ...

    if (timer1 != null)
        timer1.Dispose();

    timer1 = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null,
        next5am - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be telling the GarbageCollector to keep the local variable alive:

```
GC.KeepAlive(timer1);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. KeepAlive won't make the local variable transcend the scope in which it was declared, it will simply ensure that the object won't be eligible for garbage collection until after the call to KeepAlive.