# Timer callback doesn't work if new Process is started

Tags: c#, winforms

In the Form load I have this code which sets up a callback function to be called every 10 secs

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => updateMethod(), null, 0,
                                         10*1000);
}
```

In the updateMethod I start a new process to launch a legacy exe and read the output

```
private void updateMethod()
{
  string console_exe = "MyLegacy.Exe";
  Process prcss      = new Process();
  prcss .StartInfo.UseShellExecute        = false;
  prcss .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  prcss .StartInfo.FileName               = console_exe;
  prcss .StartInfo.Arguments              = URL + " list";
  prcss .Start();
  prcss .WaitForExit();

  string output = prcss.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
  while (null != output)
  {
    output = prcss.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

updateMethod() is called exactly twice when I run my application.
After that it is just not called.

In the updateMethod() if I return before calling the new Process, the function gets called repeatedly until I close the application.

Don't understand why this method is called twice but not after that.
Is there another way of doing this instead of new Process() ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20282443/2530848) may help, You need to store your timer in instance variable. Your timer local variable is subject to garbage collection irrespective of whether it is still running or not

Comment: System.Threading.Timer is pretty famous for its ability to get garbage collected while it is active.  It will in your code, the local variable in your Load event handler isn't enough to keep it referenced.

And nothing pretty will happen when it doesn't get garbage collected but the user closes your window.  The timer keeps ticking, you have no way to stop it.  This is a bug in your code, fixing it also solves the GC problem.