# How to run Cron job(Event schedule) in AWS Windows instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda

I have Website site URL in asp.net C#, I want to run it every night 1 AM to generate Salary.
Can somebody tell me **how it would be possible in AWS Windows Instance?**

Comment: You can use System.Threading.Timer where you can manage time interval like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282144/code-for-executing-method-every-day-at-specific-time-c-sharp-windows-service-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are asking is "I have a specific url that I want to hit every night at 1AM to kick off a process', my recommendation would be to setup a cloudwatch event that calls a custom lambda function that makes the http/https request to your application. THs would be very easy to setup and cost next to nothing to run once a day.